# How can I start an application minimized in Awesome WM

Tags: awesome-wm

I'm using Awesome WM and I want my `telegram` to start minimized. Unfortunately there is no option within the application, so I have to manually quit it (which puts it into tray).

I want to minimize it right after startup, or send the exit signal (sending it to tray).

Comment: [How do I get Skype for Linux alpha minimized to system tray at autostart](//askubuntu.com/q/814323)

Comment: I am running the latest `skypeforlinux` Ubuntu build 8.22.76.3, though for some time I have been using the setting to start minimised. It is under **Tools** -> **Settings** in the START-UP AND CLOSE section with the label **Launch Skype in the background**. I don't know what the German label would be.

Comment: @DavidPostill I made a mistake. It's Telegram. I'm using skype at work, so I confused it. Also: I was asking more generally about how to minimize applications on startup in awesome.

Answer (score 0):

"-startintray"

e.g.: awful.spawn.with_shell("telegram-desktop -startintray")